# "Upon" versus "on the basis"

Tags: meaning

What are the differences between a/ and b/ below?

> a/ The agreement will be terminated upon written notice?
>
> b/ The agreement will be terminated on the basis of written notice ?

My understanding is that a/ contains also bit of time element, while b/ is only about the method of sending. Do you think that a/ and b/ are identical or you agree with my understanding that one is with time element and the other one slightly different without time.

Comment: If this is a legal document, choice b) looks like reasonable grounds for firing your lawyer. It's unncessarily ambiguous.

Comment: The law has interpretations all its own. You can't rely on normal English conventions. Ask in legal.SE.

Answer (score 0):

"On the basis of" is one of those expressions which are widely used to **avoid** being precise. For that reason, I would be very surprised to find it used in an apparently legal context such as your example.

Your interpretation may well be right, but I don't think anybody can authoritatively confirm it.

Comment: thank you very much. What time element would you associate with "Upon"? Is it something like shortly after being received, immediately, something similar ?

Comment: I would interpret it as "immediately on receipt".

Comment: thank you, very helpful. So "upon" is much more precise from time perspective as "on the basis"?

Comment: ... I meant much more precise and explanatory ...

Comment: I mean that "on the basis" is so vague that it is not possible to tell whether it refers to time, manner, or anything else.

Comment: "Upon" referring to time is fairly literary; but is normally following by a gerund or action noun: "Upon hearing ... ", "upon receipt", "upon completion... ". "Upon written notice" is a distinctively legal idiom, and is usually (always, I think) interpreted as "upon receipt of wirtten notice".